# Where are MySQL users and passwords stored?

Tags: mysql, security

When I delete 'mysql'.'user' table I'm still able to log in as any user I've created before.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User/permission information is cached in memory. Use 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES' after editing the user table directly, to reload it. Although you might not want to do that in this case, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

DROP USER does not automatically close any open user sessions. Rather, in the event that a user with an open session is dropped, the statement does not take effect until that user's session is closed. Once the session is closed, the user is dropped, and that user's next attempt to log in will fail. This is by design.

read here : 
[MySQL Reference Manual | DROP USER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-user.html)